# In Creating a Spring Boot application with a flyway H2 embedded database I am having trouble getting the SQL file to run

Tags: spring-boot, h2, flyway

I have my SQL file titled `V2__create_shipwrech.sql`. The above file is located in the migration folder of the following path `das-boot/src/main/resources/db/migration`.

Here's the SQL content:

```
CREATE TABLE SHIPWRECK(
    ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    NAME VARCHAR(255),
    DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(2000),
    CONDITION VARCHAR(255),
    DEPTH INT,
    LATITUDE DOUBLE,
    LONGITUDE DOUBLE,
    YEAR_DISCOVERED INT
);
```

Here's my application.properties file contents:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
server.port=8080
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/dasboot
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.max-active=10
spring.datasource.max-idle=8
spring.datasource.max-wait=10000
spring.datasource.min-evictable-idle-time-millis=1000
spring.datasource.min-idle=8
spring.datasource.time-between-eviction-runs-millis=1
flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=false;
```

Here's my pom file contents:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"                
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0         
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>das-boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <name>das-boot</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.193</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

This is my first time working with Spring Boot, Flyway, and the h2 embedded database, so please for give me if I sound like a newbie at this, I am.

Here's my console output lines I think stand out to me:

```
-    Database: jdbc:h2:file:~/dasboot (H2 1.4)
-    Validated 1 migration (execution time 00:00.039s)
-    Current version of schema "PUBLIC": 2
-    Schema "PUBLIC" is up to date. No migration necessary.
-    Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
-    Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
-       name: default
-       ...]
-    Hibernate Core {4.3.11.Final}
-    hibernate.properties not found
-    HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
-    Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
-    Unrecognized value for "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto": false;
-    Looking for @ControllerAdvice:
```

Then there were a ton of debug statements saying bean that were rejected after that, which I don't have enough room to paste.

This was all using java version 1.8

Any help would be greatly appreciated and what I learn from you will be used to teach others as I progress.
Thanks in advance,
Joe

Comment: I've tried to improve the formatting of your question, but the debug output is a bit beyond help. Could you edit it with some well-formatted output and also explain why you think it's relevant? I couldn't see anything of interest in there.

Comment: Thanks Andy, much appreciated, I've trimmed down as much as i could to where I thought would be the most helpful output concerning my issue.

Comment: I the issue relates to the console output, "Unrecognized value for "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto": false;".  I've tried substituting the following for "false;"  ( "none", "false" and "").  none of these work and allowed the h2 database to run my sql code from my V2__create_shipwreck.sql file.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the property `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=false` to

`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none`